# How to perform action on RealityKit animation completion

Tags: swift, animation, arkit, realitykit

In [WWDC19 talk](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/605/) they showed how to animate Entity and perform action on animation completion  (go to minute 12 for reference) like this:

```
let animationController = move(to: flipUpTransform, relativeTo: parent, duration: 0.25, timingFunction: .easeInOut)

animationController.completionHandler {
// Perform some action
}
```

But it looks like that they removed or never added this `completionHandler`. Instead they have `isCompleted` boolean property. 
I am new to swift so I have no idea to use this `isCompleted` to perform some actions upon animation completion. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

The documentation says:

> Look for one of the events in AnimationEvents if you want to be alerted when certain aspects of animation occur.

So you can use Combine to get notified when the animation finishes. so

```swift
let animation = entity.move(to: targetTransform, relativeTo: nil, duration: 1)

arView.scene.publisher(for: AnimationEvents.PlaybackCompleted.self)
       .filter { $0.playbackController == animation }
       .sink(receiveValue: { event in
            / * your completion handler */
        }).store(in: &subscriptions)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I figured out that in RealityKit you can listen to events via `arView.scene.subscribe(to:on:completion:)`

Comment: What is the type of subscriptions?

Comment: @JaydenIrwin Thats from [Combine (AnyCancellable)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/anycancellable), just a `Set<AnyCancellable>`